# Unable to delete individual index in through ElasticSearch Head Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete some elasticsearch indexes through Head Plugin. For that i have added the index name beside the URL like http://localhost:9200/Index Name and selected Delete under Any Request tab. But some how i am getting an error like below. Can anybody please help.

"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "request [DELETE /IndexName[image]/] does not support having a body"

Comment: This my solution not solve the issue @Swarup ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request can't contain a body. Delete the curly braces `{}` from it.

[image]

Comment: While running the command it was blank...i mean it came with the response when i tried to take the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

This is an internal issue of ElasticHead. This problem is still relevant.

During execution of some queries, symbol can be added.
It triggers a fail of the query execution.

I have met the same issue on this query and on another one.
For exemple, I have executed "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty".
During the execution, "/" symbol is adding after "pretty" and triggering a fail of query.

To work around this problem, you can execute your queries with another tool as Postman.